# Find the prime number that satisfy the equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the prime number that satisfy the equations

$p + 1 = 2x^2$

$p^2 + 1 = 2y^2$

such that $(x,y)$ is an integer

and determine $(x,y)$ also

Comment: $p^2+1-p-1=2y^2-2x^2\Rightarrow p(p-1)=2(y-x)(y+x)$

Comment: 7 ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: if we try like that, the result is if p=2;y=1;x=0 
isn't it contradicition?

Comment: Algebra+number theory != Algebraic number theory.

Comment: Where is the contradiction in Integral's comment? You are perhaps reading the implication backwards. It doesn't say that every prime $p$ and integers $x,y$ such that $p(p-1)=2(y-x)(y+x)$ are solutions to your system (it says the *converse*).

Comment: not for anon but for integral
thanks for the 7

Comment: If we can infer from "the prime number" that there is only one, we are done.

Comment: Note the conditions also imply $\rm y^2-(p-1)x^2=1$, an example of Pell's equation. Still not sure how to show there is only one prime for which this is solvable (assuming this is the case).

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $p$ is odd. We can clearly choose $x, y$ to be positive integers. $2y^2=p^2+1>p+1=2x^2$, so $y>x$.

$$p(p-1)=p^2-p=2y^2-2x^2=2(y-x)(y+x)$$

Thus $p \mid y-x$ or $p \mid y+x$.

If $p \mid y-x$, then $y-x \geq p$, so $y+x>p$, and $p^2-p=2(y-x)(y+x)>2p^2$, a contradiction.

If $p \mid y+x$, then $y+x \geq p$. Thus

$$(p^2+1)+(p+1)+4xy=2(x+y)^2 \geq 2p^2$$

$$4xy \geq p^2-p-2 \geq 0$$

$$4(p^2+1)(p+1)=4(2y^2)(2x^2)=(4xy)^2 \geq (p^2-p-2)^2$$

$$p^4-6p^3-7p^2 \leq 0$$

$$p^2(p-7)(p+1) \leq 0$$

Thus $p \leq 7$.

$2=\frac{3+1}{2}$ and $3=\frac{5+1}{2}$ are not squares, so $p \not =3, 5$.

$7+1=2(\pm 2)^2, 7^2+1=2(\pm 5)^2$, so $p=7$ and $(x, y)=(\pm 2, \pm 5)$.